# Does Subversion 1.7 support relative file external paths to files in the same directory?

Tags: svn, relative-path, svn-externals

I have a directory with the following, which I'm trying to check into Subversion:

```
foo.html
foo.html --> index.html
```

That is to say, `index.html` is a symlink to `foo.html`. (Yes, I know this is silly, but we have to do it because reasons.)

`foo.html` is checked in as

```
http://svn.example.org/source/svn_repos/myproject/branches/1.0/foo.html
```

I'm trying to replace the symlink with an external. After deleting the symlink, I've tried both of the following:

```
svn propset svn:externals "foo.html index.html"
svn propset svn:externals "./foo.html index.html"
```

but on an update both produce

```
svn: warning: W125002: Unrecognized format for the relative external URL
```

According to a literal reading of the [documentation](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.externals.html) ("Relative to the URL of the directory on which the svn:externals property is set"), I tried

```
svn propset svn:externals "../foo.html index.html"
```

but on an update, this (unsurprisingly) produces:

```
svn: warning: W170000: URL 'http://svn.example.org/source/svn_repos/myproject/branches/foo.html' 
    at revision 12345 doesn't exist
```

Finally, I tried this --

```
svn propset svn:externals "../1.0/foo.html index.html"
```

-- which does work, but doesn't actually do what I want, insofar as, next time I do an `svn copy` to create say a `1.1` branch, `branches/1.1/index.html` is going to still (mistakenly) point to `branches/1.0/foo.html`.

Is there a syntax that will actually get me a relative path to the current directory, or is this just not possible?

Answer (score 1):

It's just not possible.  Read the manual about 
[SVN Externals Definition](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.externals.html) and you'll see that what you're trying to do is not present in what can be done with externals.  Externals are not symbolic links.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: I did answer the question.  The link is for further reference.